# Contributors from package.json don't show up on npm web site

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I've added contributors array in package.json but the list don't show up on project page https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.terminal

```
  "author": {
    "name": "Jakub Jankiewicz",
    "email": "jcubic@onet.pl",
    "url": "http://jcubic.pl/jakub-jankiewicz"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {"name":"Johan","url":"https://github.com/johanjordaan"},
    {"name":"Christopher John Ryan","email":"chrisjohnryan@live.com","url":"https://github.com/ChrisJohnRyan"},
    {"name":"Zuo Qiyang","email":"zuoqy.gk@gmail.com","url":"http://zuoqy.com"},
    {"name":"Sébastien Warin","url":"http://sebastien.warin.fr"},
    {"name":"Florian Schäfer","email":"florian.schaefer+github@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/fschaefer"},
    {"name":"Tomasz Ducin","email":"tomasz@ducin.it","url":"http://ducin.it"},
    {"name":"Hasan","url":"https://github.com/JuanPotato"},
    {"name":"Hraban Luyat","email":"hraban@0brg.net","url":"https://luyat.com"},
    {"name":"Mateusz Paprocki","email":"mattpap@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/mattpap"},
    {"name":"Martin v. Löwis","url":"https://github.com/loewis"},
    {"name":"Robert Wikman","email":"rbw@vault13.org","url":"flatwired.com"},
    {"name":"Steve Phillips","email":"steve@tryingtobeawesome.com","url":"https://tryingtobeawesome.com/"},
    {"name":"coderaiser","email":"mnemonic.enemy@gmail.com","url":"http://coderaiser.github.io"},
    {"name":"Juraj Vitko","url":"https://github.com/youurayy"},
    {"name":"Yutong Luo","email":"yutong@yutongluo.com","url":"https://yutongluo.com"}
  ],
```

here is my [package.json file](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/master/package.json)

I've reported that on [github](https://github.com/npm/www/issues/122) but after two days with no response I decide to ask on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the "Collaborators" box on the right sidebar of the module page. They do sound similar but they are different things. NPM doesn't use the `contributors` field to populate that list, but [you can add people to it manually or through the CLI](https://docs.npmjs.com/all#giving-access-to-others).

Comment: that clarify things but that link is for private packages and it's about giving access to the package to other people.

Comment: Yes, because that is the main purpose of the collaborators feature. You can add your contributors to it "just for show" on public modules as well, but the original functionality was intended to give access to private modules. :)

Comment: It didn't help me. I added owner using command `npm owner add...` and nothing happened.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem. CLI command `npm owner add` didn't give me result. I found other way that works for me:

1. Go to 'Admin' tab on your package page and invite maintainer (simply type in npm user login you want to be collaborator).
2. Press button 'Update Package Settings' above 'Maintainers' block.

After these steps your package will have one more collaborator!

[image]

Comment: This is confusing it should be named `Maintainers` not `collaborators`, which is more like contributors than the admins.